# Wordpress Page always Reload Old Cache (LiteSpeed)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, litespeed

My Wordpress run on Google Cloud Platform using `LiteSpeed` WebServer, below are the specifications:

- WordPress 5.4.1
- PHP 7.3
- OpenLiteSpeed 1.6.13
- phpMyAdmin 5.0.2
- MariaDB 10.4
- Redis 5.0.7
- Memcached 1.5.22
- CertBot 0.40.0

However, after updating my page, **it always reloads old page cache.**

I have tried below steps:

1. Purge Cache, by `disable` / `enable` cache on **LiteSpeed Cache Plugin**. I can see notification said `Purged all caches successfully.`
2. Disable All Plugins
3. Reboot VPS

But still cant solve it, the old page still show.

Any Idea to solve this issue?

==Update: `.htaccess`

```
BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
### marker LOGIN COOKIE start ###
RewriteRule .? - [E="Cache-Vary:wp-postpass_07cx34bxfgxrbttrt56"]
### marker LOGIN COOKIE end ###
### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###
</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: try 1)  cache ---> purge --->  purge stale to OFF.  2) empty everyting in /usr/local/lsws/cachedata/  3)  restart OLS

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation ones but at the time I was using elementor to make page changes. After making changes, saving and closing, initial results before changes would show instead of the new changes, Later realized at the time, the LiteSpeed Cache Plugin was not working well elementor. To test this,

1. I had to disable the cache cleaner plugin and see if the new page changes would take effect. If so,
2. Went forward to look for compatible cache cleaner that best works with elementor.

The issue is most commonly a certain plugin interfering with the theme, you didn't have to even edit the .htaccess file, but that's my share. Hope it somehow helps.